# complex matlab for loop with matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

I don't understand this piece of code of a `for` loop in matlab, I know that loops in matlab usually look like: `for ii=1:2:100` so that it starts in 1 until 100 and in each iteration you add 2.
But here I've got this condition in the loop and I don't get what it does:

```
for ii=[1:w:rd(1)-w-border, rd(1)-w-border+1],
   ...
end;
```

`w` and `border` are integers passed as arguments and `rd` is size of the image/matrix (`rd = size(image);`)

Can someone explain me how for loops work in matlab with this kind of condition? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: to me it looks like a standard `MATLAB` loop: I'd recommend you to understand what happens within the square brackets `[]`. For the rest, @Shai gave you some valuable hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`For` loop in matlab can execute statements for a defined set of index values:
For example, the following code will display all the element in the set `[1,5,8,17]`:

```
for s = [1,5,8,17]
 disp(s)
end
```

Your code `for ii=[1:w:rd(1)-w-border, rd(1)-w-border+1]` is similar.
Its just like a set `1:w:rd(1)-w-border` with an additional element `rd(1)-w-border+1`.

Its like writing this set `[1,2,3,4,5,8]` as `[1:1:5, 8]`
I hope its clear now.

Answer (score 2):

the `for` argument is a vector. the loop iterator `ii` takes one value for the vector for each iteration of the loop. As you mentioned, the vector can be equally spaced one like `1:2:100`. But it can also be arbitrary, for example `for ii = [4,6,1,8] ...`.
In you case the `for` argument vector is partly "equally spaced" vector: `1:w:rd(1)-w-border` plus another element `rd(1)-border+1`.